# Unable to get Atom text editor from the Software Center

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, atom

I'm unable to get Atom text editor from the Software Center. When I try I get this error:

```
Package does not exist.
Check the spelling of the package name, and that the appropriate repository is enabled.
```

Comment: What PPA did you add to your system?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Its not available in official ubuntu repos you have to add a third party ppa(which may or may not be continued to be maintained) or you do have direct debian package in their site..https://atom.io/

Comment: so can you walk me through on how to get atom

Comment: @Galien1 check Kaz Wolfe's answer..would go with that

Comment: Atom package does exist in the Ubuntu Software app in my Ubuntu 16.04. Click the *Install* button to install it (see the screenshot in my answer). If that doesn't work try installing Atom from the terminal. Don't forget to include the `--classic` option when installing Atom from the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Run these commands to quickly and easily install and upgrade the Atom text editor snap package from the terminal in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu (64-bit only).

- Install Atom text editor:

  ```
  sudo apt install snapd  
  sudo snap install --classic atom
  ```

  Note that a snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, and Atom extension packages are installed into the user's home directory.
- Upgrade Atom text editor:

  ```
  sudo snap refresh --classic atom
  ```

Atom text editor can also be installed from the Ubuntu Software application in Ubuntu 16.04 as shown in the below screenshot. Either way there is no need to add a PPA to your software sources.

[image]

Atom is more than just another text editor. Atom is extensible through the installation of Atom packages that can give Atom the capabilities of running code, showing inline graphical output and more.

[image]
<sup>**Inline plot in Atom**</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Atom is not available from the standard Ubuntu repositories:

```
┌─[22:57:03]─[kazwolfe@firewolf]
└──> ~ % apt-cache madison atom
      atom | 1.18.0-1~webupd8~0 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

In order to install Atom, you need to either [download the debfile](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.18.0) and install that, or add the Webupd8 Atom PPA.

For the former (direct debfile), run these commands:

```
wget -O /tmp/atom.deb https://atom.io/download/deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/atom.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Alternatively, if you'd rather use the PPA and allow Apt to manage your installation (which I personally recommend), run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt update
sudo apt install atom
```

Comment: after i run the ppa i get this                                                                                       Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package atom

Comment: @Galien1 You also ran `sudo apt update` after adding the PPA? You need to run this to have Ubuntu update its package caches and recognize the new PPA.

Comment: should i run                                                                                                                                       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt update
sudo apt install atom                                                                                                                       sudo apt update

Comment: @Galien1 they are three separate commands

Comment: @Galien1: Yes. Copy and paste each command one at a time. Each command is on its own line.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @Galien1: What is the exact error message you're getting now? For the record, [this](https://pastebin.com/AbELajui) is what a successful installation of Atom looks like via the PPA method.

Comment: Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found

Comment: Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done                       
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: @Galien1: That error message should be irrelevant in this case. It just means that the FFMPEG-NEXT PPA is not being found. You can disable it from the **Software & Updates** settings menu. That error should not impede your installation of `atom`, though. Try running `sudo apt install atom`.

Comment: I did that and tried installing more than once

Comment: Do you have a specific error message this time, other than the PPA error?