# I upgrade Atom but its version does not change

Tags: 16.04, atom

I am an Ubuntu 16.04 user and want to upgrade Atom to use the teletype package.

What I do is:

1. Go to Atom's releases page (https://github.com/atom/atom/releases )
2. Download the latest version which is 1.24.0-beta1 (atom-amd64.deb) and run

   ```
   sudo dpkg --install atom-amd64.deb
   ```

   it says

   ```
   Unpacking atom-beta (1.24.0-beta1) over (1.23.0-beta1)
   ```

When I check atom's version with `atom -v` I get:

```
Atom : 1.20.1
Electron: 1.6.9
Chrome : 56.0.2924.87
Node : 7.4.0
```

Why?

Comment: what happens when you call `/usr/share/atom-beta/atom -v`?

Comment: My Atom is not beta, it's version 1.23.1 and I installed it from the Ubuntu Software app in Ubuntu 16.04. For more information see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/933141/unable-to-get-atom-txt-editor-from-software-center/934620#934620

Comment: Thanks for help guys. Firstly, there is no atom-beta folder under /usr/share it's just atom. And I  found out that atom-beta does not override atom. They are installed separately so I installed teletype package in atom-beta.

Answer (score 1):

My Atom is not beta, it's version 1.23.1 and I installed it from the Ubuntu Software app in Ubuntu 16.04. For information about how to  install Atom, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/933141/unable-to-get-atom-txt-editor-from-software-center/934620#934620). I installed the teletype 0.40 package in Atom from *Packages* -> *Settings View* -> *Install Packages/Themes*.